# Visual Basic If website contains certain text

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to build a program **in Visual Basic** that reacts to the text I put on my website. For example the program goes to my school website and if my school's website says "School is Closed" it will display the text "No School" on the program.

Something like this:

```
webbrowser1.navigate("www.mysite.com")
if <Webpage contains the words "School is Closed"> then
     label1.text = "No School"
end if
```

I have done it before, so I know it is possible, I just don't remember how. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `webbrowser1.navigate`, does this return the webpage as a string? Also, please tag your programming langauge (this looks like Visual Basic to me).

Comment: @cybermonkey yes it is visual basic as it says in the title. It doesn't have to use "webbrowser1.navigate" i just need something that works.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow isn't a 'write this code for me' site, and as a result don't be surprised if you are downvoted. I have provided an answer, please provide feedback to whether this works for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is as per se:

```
Imports System.Net
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim strin As String = New WebClient().DownloadString(("http://example.com"))
        If strin.Contains("is closed") Then
            Label1.Text = "School"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[Adapted from this.](http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/2013/09/down-for-everyone-or-just-me-in-vbnet.html)

Comment: That code got me further to solving my problem however Visual Studio gives me an error for the "IndexOf".

Comment: @FORBIDENxKROSS I just logged onto my laptop of which has Visual Studio installed, I'll get back to you once I have the code working fully.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to my problem here:
http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/2013/09/down-for-everyone-or-just-me-in-vbnet.html

The reason I was having problems is because I did not import the System.Net namespace.